# Passing Arrays as a parameter to a VBA function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a user defined Excell worksheet function (Linear) that interpolates from an array of X and an array of Y values at a defined X1 value, which works fine. I have tried to use this within another function (NPL in the example code below) be setting it a a Private Static function within a VBA module and then calling the function using arrays of data created within the function.
When I use this in the spreadsheet I get a #VALUE error.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Example code:

```
Function NPL(Length, Beam)
A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
B = Array(2, 4, 6, 8)
C = Linear(A, B, 1.5)
NPL = C


End Function
Private Static Function Linear(X, Y, X1)

N = 0
I = 1
Do
N = I
I = I + 1
Loop Until X(I) < X(I - 1) Or N = X.Count

A = 0
I = 0
Do
I = I + 1
Loop Until X(I) > X1 Or I > N - 1

If X1 < X(N) And X1 > X(1) Then
Linear = Y(I - 1) + (X1 - X(I - 1)) * (Y(I) - Y(I - 1)) / (X(I) - X(I - 1))
ElseIf X1 > X(N) Or X1 = X(N) Then
Linear = Y(N)
Else
Linear = Y(1)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: have you stepped through code? There is probably a logical error which you can most likely identify by stepping through

Comment: Arrays in VBA don't have properties so you can't use `X.Count`

Comment: `Loop Until X(I) < X(I - 1) Or N = UBound(X) - LBound(X) - 1`

Comment: Yes I have now and have found my problem, sorry!

Comment: Hi. Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your

```
Do
    N = I
    I = I + 1
Loop Until X(I) < X(I - 1) Or N = X.Count
```

with

```
Do
    N = I
    I = I + 1
Loop Until X(I) < X(I - 1) Or N = UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1
```

This should work for any 1D array.